# Which distro to use for learning linux(job perspective)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, distro

Which distro to use for learning linux(from job perspective). Which distro is used by most software companies? I was wondering about whether to go for RHEL or Ubuntu or any other. What would be the best choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think it matters nearly as much as how comfortable you are with a Linux environment and the tools available (and knowing *about* the tools available, and how to use them).

I have been using Unix/Linux since the early 1990s, and I still come across stuff I didn't know about. One of the *major* strengths of this OS is the wide range of tools available and the flexibility of accomplishing tasks by sometimes combining them.

Once you are comfortable in a Linux environment, the adjustment to a given distribution will be minor. You'd probably notice changing your default shell more than changing the distribution :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are comfortable with major linux utilities like find/grep/sed/awk and bash in general, you should be fine.However most major distributions are based on either RPM or debs, knowing about these two packaging mechanisms will be a big help. Concepts like firewalls, RAID 
and file permissions are needed on daily basis being system admin related work.